# Set font name, size and color for selected subtitle with VLCJ

Tags: java, vlcj, spu

Currently I am working on some code based on VLCJ to play media content.

I am focused on subtitles tracks, and I would like to add functionality to modify the font name, size and color of the subtitle being played. Is there any way to get this functionality working?

Do you know if in future vlcj releases this functionality would be added?

Thanks a lot in advance.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API in LibVLC to set subtitle attributes, so consequently there's no API in vlcj to do that either.

To see how to change subtitle attributes in VLC, go to a command-line/shell and type:

```
vlc -H
```

Then search that output for "freetype", you will see a whole bunch of switches for setting subtitle attributes, e.g.

```
--freetype-font
--freetype-fontsize
--freetype-opacity
--freetype-color
```

...and so on.

There are two ways to use these command-line switches with LibVLC/vlcj, and which way to use depends on the particular option. If it doesn't work one way, try the other.

Either:

- when you create the `MediaPlayerFactory` you pass the switches as arguments; or
- when you invoke `mediaPlayer.playMedia(mrl, options)` you pass the switches as options.

So pass something like:

```
String[] args = {
    "--freetype-color"  , "12632256",
    "--freetype-opacity", "128"
};
```

The situation is different e.g. with DVD subtitles - you can't change those attributes at all.

If VLC ever exposed new API to support setting of subtitle attributes, a future release of vlcj would undoubtedly add it.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for the quick answer, I will try to play with this 2 methods you exposed.

Comment: When used via MediaPlayerFactory it works. The problem is executing in Windows "vlc.exe -H" all the options overpass the buffer of the cmd window. Could you please, share the -H output, so I can see all the properties related to freetype, and how to set its values? Because the color seems to be a kind of code diferente from hexadeciaml, like e.g. #66FFFF. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "vlc.exe -H > vlc.txt" then "notepad vlc.txt" or whatever.

Comment: Thanks again. I needed to execute the CMD as admin to get the exepcted output :)